# Iterate dict in python using next()

Tags: python, dictionary

Is it possible to iterate dictionary in python using `next()`. (I need to access keys and values). Also would it work for extendable dictionaries with non-fixed length?

Comment: There's no such thing as a fixed length dictionary in Python.  All dictionaries are "extendable" in the sense that their contents can change dynamically.  You can iterate over key/value dictionary pairs with `items()` - https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items

Comment: Dictionaries aren't iterators, so you can't use `next()` on them. Neither is `dict_items`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `items` to get the pairs key/value and `iter()` to be able to call `next`

```
content = dict(zip(range(10), range(10, 20)))
print(content)  # {0: 10, 1: 11, 2: 12, 3: 13, 4: 14, 5: 15, 6: 16, 7: 17, 8: 18, 9: 19}

iterable = iter(content.items())
print(next(iterable))  # (0, 10)
print(next(iterable))  # (1, 11)
print(next(iterable))  # (2, 12)
print(next(iterable))  # (3, 13)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, it is possible to iterate over a dictionary using `next` (and `iter`). In fact, this is how iteration works:

   1. Obtain an iterator: `__it = iter(your_dict)`
   2. Call `next(__it)` to retrieve the next *key*
2. Iterating over a dictionary iterates over its *keys*: `list({1: 'hello', 2: 'world'}) == [1, 2]`. You should iterate over `your_dict.items()` to get pairs of keys and values